# Trouble with composer autoloading and namespaces

Tags: composer-php, autoload

I'm trying to create a Packagist/Composer package for some training if namespaces and composer. I cannot figure out how to allow autoloading from `vendor/autoload.php`.

Actual code can be seen here: `https://github.com/ThomasKasper/Passthrough` or as an example below.

This is my filestructure:

```
root
|---composer.json
|---src
    |----Passthrough
       |----Folder1
            |SomeClass.php
       |----Folder2
       |----Folder3
       |----Folder4
```

composer.json:

```
{
"name": "passthrough/passthrough",
"description": "A simple MVC framework",
"license": "MIT",
"keywords": ["passthrough", "framework"],
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.0"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Passthrough\\": "src/Passthrough"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Passthrough\\": "src/Passthrough"
    }
}
}
```

An example class:

```
<?php

namespace Passthrough\Folder1;

class SomeClass
{

}
```

App.php

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Passthrough\Folder1\SomeClass;

$route = new SomeClass();

var_dump($route);


Fatal error: Class 'Passthrough\Folder1\SomeClass' not found in C:\wamp\www\PassthroughTester\app.php on line 7
```

Comment: Did you install your package with Composer or did you run `composer dump-autoload` else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your example script did not fail including `vendor/autoload.php`, we can safely assume that you actually have run

```
$ composer dump-autoload
```

However, if you have modified your autoloading configuration *after* running aforementioned command, then maybe that is a reason why the class cannot be found.

Furthermore, assuming that autoloading has been set up correctly, then the only reason why the script fails could be that the class `Passthrough\Folder1\SomeClass` does not exist in `src/Passthrough/Folder1/SomeClass.php`, where the autoloader would actually be looking for it.

### Guesswork

Guessing, from your example script and the link to your repository that the example could actually look like this:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Passthrough\Routing\Route\Route;

$route = new Route('foo', function () {
    // . . . 
});

var_dump($route);
```

then the output is this:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Passthrough\Base\Data\Callback' not found in /Users/am/Sites/stackoverflow/34509692/src/Passthrough/Routing/Route/Route.php on line 92
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /Users/am/Sites/stackoverflow/34509692/app.php:0
PHP   2. Passthrough\Routing\Route\Route->__construct() /Users/am/Sites/stackoverflow/34509692/app.php:7

Fatal error: Class 'Passthrough\Base\Data\Callback' not found in /Users/am/Sites/stackoverflow/34509692/src/Passthrough/Routing/Route/Route.php on line 92
```

and the reason for that is that the class `Passthrough\Base\Data\Callback` referenced in [`Passthrough\Routing\Route\Route::__construct()`](https://github.com/ThomasKasper/Passthrough/blob/master/src/Passthrough/Routing/Route/Route.php#L92) actually doesn't exist in your project.

### Unrelated

Unrelated to your question, but there's no point in setting up the same autoloading for development as well as non-development environments, you should adjust `composer.json` accordingly and remove the `autoload-dev` section:

```
{
    "name": "passthrough/passthrough",
    "description": "A simple MVC framework",
    "license": "MIT",
    "keywords": ["passthrough", "framework"],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Passthrough\\": "src/Passthrough"
        }
    }
}
```

For reference, see https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload-dev.

Comment: This was me being a complete idiot, thanks for pointing out my idiocy.